# Dynamic auth.token based on resource.data

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to write a rule allowing an user to access only the documents he has access to:

```
match /websites/{website} {
    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth.uid != null;
    }
    function isAuthorized(rsc) {
      return request.auth.token[rsc.data.role] == true
    }
    function isAdmin() {
      return request.auth.token.admin == true
    }

    allow read, write: if isSignedIn() && (isAuthorized(resource) || isAdmin());
}
```

Seems like there is a issue with `request.auth.token[rsc.data.role]` but I can't figure out what's the problem. `rsc.data.role` is set as a string in the database, and my user as a token as a boolean. 
Example: `website.role: 'editor'` and `request.auth.token.editor: true`.

Here's a screenshot of the document I'm trying to access:
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: There's really not enough information here.  You should show the contents of the document you're writing, as well as the contents of the auth token that you've verified to be correct.  You should also independently test each function to verify that they each work as you expect, hard coding values as necessary to separate them each from one another.

Comment: I'm not writing documents, just read for now. And I tested the functions individually. Only `isAuthorized ` is not working. I think I'm not getting the resource the right way (the one I'm reading). If I write the function like `return request.auth.token.editor == true`, it's working.

Comment: Then show the document you are reading, so we can examine for ourselves what's going on here.  Also you could take a screenshot to make it absolutely clear.

Comment: Basically I'm trying to filter websites by user's right. But maybe that's not something I can do in firestore rules.

Comment: No, you can't filter queries based on security rules.  The moment a rule encounters any document in the query that fails the rules, the entire query will fail.  It would have helped spot that if you also mentioned that you were going a query (as opposed to a get), and showed that query in your question.

Comment: Right, I updated my query with the role `query.where('role', '==', 'junkichi')` and it's working just fine. I get it now.